# Dropdown displays just id on form error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4, dropdownbox

I've created a drop-down for one of my forms in my Rails application.

I am using simple-form.

My drop-down field looks like the following:

```
<%= f.input :event_id, collection: Event.where(type: ["track and field", "ice", "gymnastics"])
```

First..I feel like having this query in the view is just awful. However, when I move the query to the controller action, and I experience a form error (such as a required field wasn't filled out), when the page refreshes the drop-down just shows an integer (id) instead of the name that it previously showed. I feel like the param is being lost.

Thoughts?

Comment: `f.association :event, collection: Event.require_type, prompt: "Choose a event"` in event model `scope :require_type, -> {where(type: ["track and field", "ice", "gymnastics"])}`

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that I would do is delegate the query to the model via scope like this:

```
# app/models/event.rb
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
    #Event.special_events
    scope :special_events ->{ where(type: ["track and field", "ice", "gymnastics"]) }
  ...
end
```

now in your view you can do something like this

```
<%= f.input :event_id, collection: Event.special_events) %>
```